# informatica scenario complex

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Scenario:

if you run  for the first time,first target table must load,if you run  for the second time,second target table must load,
similarly third,fourth    How to solve this scenario?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you elaborate a bit as to why such a scenario is required? It seems very odd.

Comment: How many tables are there? Perhaps it would be enough to set up a individual workflows (reusing the same mapping) and schedule them according to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a sequence generator that increments each time the job is run. Just have a list of the target tables (in order) and do a lookup on the current sequence value.